# How to setup download path of chrome in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am using robotframework to automate test cases, there are requirement file download functionality.

Can any one suggest how to update default download path of chrome.

I implemented below are sample code:

```
${chrome options}=    Evaluate    
sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${download directory}    Join Path    ${EXECDIR}    downloads
create directory  ${download directory}
${prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${download directory}
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a [mcve] of the technical issue you're currently facing? At [so] we aim to help you with programming issues and expect some effort to have been spent on your part. In this case a [simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bselenium%5D+chrome+download+location) on Stack Overflow would help you with this particular issue.

Comment: I resolved the configuration  and updated code in question

Comment: Just to confirm: the code in the question is working code and there is no longer an issue?

Comment: Yes, that is working...

Comment: @SadikAli Please provided me another information, I try to follow your code but it struck with `Join Path` keyword is not found.